# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for EventsComponent (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

Can anyone figure out why my EventService can't be injected into my EventsComponent? 
I get this error in the chrome console:
`Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for EventsComponent: (?, ?).`

https://github.com/andrelin/ng-fundamentals

I have tried googling this, and looked at several different answers here on StackOverflow, but everything seems to be correct. Some suggest there might be a circular dependency somewhere in the project, but I really can not find any circular dependency. Does anyone have a suggestion for this?

My (simplified) AppModule:

```
import { EventService } from './events/services/event.service';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EventsComponent } from './events/events.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, EventsComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [EventService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My EventComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from './services/event.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-events',
  templateUrl: './events.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events.component.css']
})
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {
  events: any[];

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.events = this.eventService.getEvents();
  }
}
```

My EventService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventService {
  constructor() {}

  getEvents() {
    return EVENTS;
  }
}
```

Sample Events array

```
const EVENTS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Angular Connect',
    date: '9/26/2020',
    time: '8:00 am',
    price: 599.99,
    imageUrl: '/assets/images/angualrconnect-shield.png',
    location: {
      address: '1057 DT',
      city: 'London',
      country: 'England'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Angular Netherlands',
    date: '10/10/2021',
    time: '10:00 am',
    price: 60,
    imageUrl: '/assets/images/ng-nl.png',
    location: {
      address: 'A very long address just to make this two lines!',
      city: 'Amsterdam',
      country: 'Netherlands'
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: Is there any JSON pipe used in events.component.html may cause circular dependency problem

Comment: There's just an *ngFor to iterate the events property: <h1>Upcoming Angular Events</h1>
 <hr />
         <div class="row">
          <div *ngFor="let event of events" class="col-md-5">
             <app-event-thumbnail #thumbnail (clickEvent)="handleClickEvent($event)" [inputEvent]="event"></app-event-thumbnail>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: When you got circular dependency injection? I downloaded your project its working fine for me

Comment: I get this error in the console in the browser: Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for EventsComponent: (?, ?).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but adding this line `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` to top of  `main.ts` solved this problem for me.
check the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fxudou), got this solution from angular-cli's [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10919).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `EventService` from providers array **app.module.ts** or `providedIn` from **.service.ts** .

Answer (score 0):

I found and have added "emitDecoratorMetadata": true in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
```